# Can a teenager open an account without UPI?

Tags: india, paypal

Can a 16-17-year-old establish a PayPal/Paytm/Google Pay account in the absence of UPI? I'm under the age of 18. I am originally from India. I don't have a checking account. All I have is a phone number (not registered under my name). I also have a passport, an Aadhar card, and other identification documents. What are the additional criteria for using PayPal, Paytm, and so on? I'm also curious about UPI and how it works. Will I be able to utilise the UPI feature for PayPal, Paytm, PhonePe, Google Pay, and other services? Are there any services that allow payments without the use of UPI?

Comment: Since you don't have a bank account, and presumably not a credit card either, how exactly do you plan on making payments or sending money via PayPal etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was watching a YouTube movie the other day when I saw [FamPay](https://fampay.in/) and [Akudo](https://www.akudo.in/) advertisings. Minors can use FamPay to make UPI, P2P, and card payments without having to have a bank account. FamPay allows parents to transfer money to their children under the age of 18, which they may spend safely at any time and from any location under the supervision of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Logn answer short ~ Yes, but not legally.

You must have your parent or legal guardian's permission to use Google Pay and to accept the Terms. Google Pay requires a bank account to be added till then Google Pay is unable to send or receive money.

I would recommend using a family payment method on Google Play

Comment: It is not _illegal_ to give you an account as a minor, but it is a _voidable_ contract, which you can void at any time, so it is very risky for a company to accept you as a customer. You don’t need permission of your guardian, but your guardian can also void any contract that you enter. So nothing illegal, but there are big practical problems.